# loop different rows from dataframe A and apply them to the same individual rows in dataframe B

Tags: r, loops, matrix, matrix-multiplication, hamming-distance

As I am working on a Q-Matrix question and needing to calculate hamming distance, I am having problem of different rows (as vectors) from `dataframe A` to the same row in `dataframe B`.

Specifically, `df2` is a 6x3 dataframe and `df1` is a 3x3 dataframe.

```
    df1 <- data.frame(Q1= c(1,0,1), Q2= c(0,0,0), Q3= c(1,1,0))
    df2 <- data.frame(A =c(1,1,0,1,1,0), B =c(0,0,0,1,1,0), C =c(0,1,0,1,1,1))
```

I need to apply all 6 rows from  `df2` as vectors into every row in `df1` sequentially in order calculate the hamming distance of all 6 vector - 1 vector pair (it should output 3 hamming distance values only). For instance, for the 1st row in `df1` which is `(1,0,1)` should be paired with all 6 rows in `df2` including `(1,0,0),(1,0,1),(0,0,0),(1,1,1),(1,1,1),(0,0,1)`and produce 1 hamming distance value. Following the same logic, this similar process should give 3 hamming distance values.

I have tried a few times with `double for() loop` but with no success. In fact, I don't even know how we print out a row from a `dataframe` as a vector that could do other calculation with other vector. Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df1)){
  print(sum(apply(df2,1,function(x) x!=df1[i,])))
  }

[1] 6
[1] 8
[1] 8
```